# John came direct/directly from London

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

Choose the correct sentence.

> A. John came **direct** from London
>
> B. John came **directly** from London.
>
> C. John **directly** came from London.

The given answer is **A.**

**directly** is an adverb. So what is the error in B and C?

Answer (score 1):

I would understand:

**direct from London** to mean that he did not stop or deviate on the way. A direct flight is one that goes from your departure point to your intended destination without intermediate stops.

**directly from London** to mean that he wasted no time in coming from London. He came directly (meaning **immediately**) after getting the news.

The person who set the test was either unaware of the alternative meaning or had the first meaning in mind.